# Making a complex framed box

Tags: boxes, mdframed

I need to realize a complex series of framed boxes as in the image, but I have no idea about how to male it. Anyone can help me? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: That is better drawn directly in TikZ, then the various parts are easier to place

Comment: Are the widths of cells proportional to the number inside?

Comment: Yes, the cells have to be proportional to the number